# Button moves when an element's display goes from "none" to "block"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an element appear when a button is clicked, but when it is, the button moves down. When the button is clicked again, it moves back up.

```js
var p = document.getElementById("p");
function changeDisplay() {
 if (p.style.display == "block") {
  p.style.display = "none";
 } else {
  p.style.display = "block";
 }
}
```

```html
<p id="p" style="display: none;">Hello World</p>
<button onclick="changeDisplay()">Button</button>
```

I could move the button below the p but then another element would just be moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) property instead. This will hide the element (`p`), but won't take it out of the layout:

```js
var p = document.getElementById("p");

function changeDisplay() {
  if (p.style.visibility == "visible") {
    p.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    p.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="p" style="visibility: hidden;">Hello World</p>
<button onclick="changeDisplay()">Button</button>
```

And a bit shorter using a ternary (suggested by [@AlexandrVyshnyvetskyi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59010696/button-moves-when-an-elements-display-goes-from-none-to-block/59010716?noredirect=1#comment104269495_59010716)):

```js
var p = document.getElementById('p');

function changeDisplay() {
  p.style.visibility = (p.style.visibility === 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
}
```

```html
<p id="p" style="visibility: hidden;">Hello World</p>
<button onclick="changeDisplay()">Button</button>
```

Comment: can be a bit shorter

`p.style.visibility = p.style.visibility == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible";`

Comment: I've tried to maintain the original structure, but indeed I would use a ternary (I'll add it to the answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allocate space for the hidden element instead of using **"display"** to toggle view  use **"visibility"** property.

```
if (p.style.visibility == "hidden") {   
    p.style.visibility = "visible";     
} else { 
    p.style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}
```

The only difference between them is that the browser allocate spaces for 
***visibility: hidden*** elements.

Hope this helps.